# How to add an “open in new excel” in windows file explorer context menu?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, windows-explorer, context-menu

I've asked a similar question before, about [How to add a "duplicate this folder" in windows file explorer context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/1191537/how-to-add-a-duplicate-this-folder-in-windows-file-explorer-context-menu) .

Similarly, is there an easy way, to add an item to windows explorer's context menu, i.e., when right click on a folder "X", there's a new item "open this in new excel", such that after clicking, the file will be opened not in current excel sessions, but in a new excel window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [source](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/05/31/excel-workbooks-separate-windows/)

### Create a Send-To-Excel shortcut

1. Open this folder : `C:/Users/UserName/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/SendTo`

You might have to show hidden and system files to be able to view the folder **AppData**. Change `UserName` to whatever your username is.

2. Create a shortcut to Excel there. You can copy an existing Excel shortcut on desktop or taskbar.