# How to add an “open in new excel with macros disabled” in windows file explorer context menu?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, windows-explorer, context-menu

I've asked similar questions before, about [How to add an “open in new excel” in windows file explorer context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/1218639/how-to-add-an-open-in-new-excel-in-windows-file-explorer-context-menu) and [How to add a "duplicate this folder" in windows file explorer context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/1191537/how-to-add-a-duplicate-this-folder-in-windows-file-explorer-context-menu) .

Similarly, is there an easy way, to add an item to windows explorer's context menu, i.e., when right click on a folder "X", there's a new item "open this in new excel **with macros disabled**", such that after clicking, the file will be opened not in current excel sessions, but in a new excel window, and the macros will be disabled, i.e. events such as Workbook_Open() won't be triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [source](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/356958-how-to-open-a-spreadsheet-with-macros-disabled.html)

Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while the workbook is opening. Unfortunately there is no parameter can be set on a shortcut to disable macro.

You can also set Disable Macro and set a trusted location so it will automatically disable macros but from files opening from the trusted location.

### [Setting Macro Security in Office 2013](http://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/enable-macros-in-excel/)

1. Go to **File > Options > Trust Center**
2. Select **Macro Settings**
3. Select either **Disable all macros without notification** or **Disable all macros with notification** (recommended)
4. Select **Trusted Locations**
5. Select **Add New Location** to make a folder trusted location.

Comment: i can't manually change the trusted sites for each excel files. i'm looking for a way to autmatically suppress the macros.

Comment: Unfortunately, currently there is no automatic suppression other than using Trust Center.